# Asymp. Integrals

Tags: integration, asymptotics, perturbation-theory

I am trying to get a two-terms asymptotic expansion ****{as $c\to 0 $ }**** for the following integral

$$\int_{0}^{c} \sqrt{\frac{c^2-\zeta^2}{1-\zeta^2}} d\zeta$$

I have tried so far to substitute $\zeta=c\ sin(\theta)$  and got the following form
$$c^2\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{cos^2\theta}{\sqrt{1-c^2sin^2\theta}} d\theta$$

how do I proceed from here?

Comment: As an option, you can expand the square root in powers of $c$: $(1-c^2\sin^2\theta)^{-1/2}$$= 1+\frac{c^2}{2}\sin^2\theta+\frac{3c^4}{8}\sin^4\theta+ ...$

Comment: By expanding the square root I cannot apply the limit condition as c^2 multiplies the whole integral  does not cancel out

Comment: Yes, you can. Your first asymptotic term$ =c^2\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^2\theta d\theta\,\,\sim c^2$, second $\sim c^4$, etc.